# Tibco-JDBC: Connection test failed

Tags: oracle, tibco, jdbc-odbc, tibco-business-works

I am trying to connect to database in tibco bw 5.12.0.
In test connection i am getting below error in popup

"AEADB-800064: Connection test failed.

```
([tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver]No more data available to read.)"
```

Console log:-

```
2017 Mar 09 17:27:09:398 GMT +0530 MetadataAdapter Info [Database] AEADB-100010 
    jdbc connection as : Driver tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver, URL jdbc:tibcosoftwareinc:oracle://127.0.0.1:8080;SID=XE, User System

Trampoline error: com.tibco.ae.tools.palettes.adb.DesignTimeAdapterProxy@4255ce57 connect
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.util.Trampoline.invoke(Trampoline.java:136)
    at com.tibco.ui.BusyWait.run(BusyWait.java:428)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver]No more data available to read.
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.b(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcr.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcq.b(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcq.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.ddcq.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.net8.ddj.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.ah(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleImplConnection.z(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.b(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.k(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseConnection.a(Unknown Source)
    at tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oraclebase.BaseDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.ae.adb.metadataadapter.Agent.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.tibco.ae.adb.metadataadapter.EmbeddedAgentManager.connect(Unknown Source)
:
:   
Connection test failed.
connected: false
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to "Oracle database might have the Oracle Advanced Security (OAS)" authentication enabled by default. please check using below query and and if it returns true then disable authentication.

select parameter, value from v$option where upper(parameter) like '%SECURITY%'